# .NET Framework Internals

Tags: .net, frameworks

Can anyone tell a book which covers a in-depth coverage of .NET Framework (2.0, 3.5 or 4.0)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)

Comment: I know this is 2 year old question. Hope this helps for other visitors. Here is one of the nice tutorial on .Net Framework internals : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S8

Answer (score 2):

It's not only the framework that has evolved but so has the languages. [Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) covers that for C# in [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The Apress "Pro C#/VB 2010 and the .Net Platform" books are pretty good, as is the "Microsoft .Net Internals" book - lots of information in both at all levels of the .Net framework.

Comment: I have Pro C# 2008 and it is one of the worst book about the topic I have ever seen.

Comment: Would you care to expand on that?  I find it to be quite a good resource to have on my desk.

Comment: That book is more like set of introductions to all available APIs. Tutorial to ASP.NET, tutorial to WPF, tutorial to WCF, tutorial to WF, ... I expected the book about CLR and advanced topics about .NET (beacuse of PRO title). There is of course coverage of some basic CLR topics but when I compare it to CLR via C# I get only disappointment.